# maximum number combinations

Tags: python, combinations

I am trying to generate a list of all possible number combinations within a set of four numbers using all numbers from 0 through 9.

I'm getting close but the output doesn't show every possible combination starting from 0000 all the way to 9999.

Any clues as to why the following code is dropping certain combinations?

```
def permgen(items, n):
  if n==0: yield []
    else:
        for i in range(len(items)):
            for cc in permgen(items[:i]+items[i+1:],n-1):
                yield [items[i]]+cc

if __name__=="__main__":
    for c in permgen(['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],4): print ''.join(c)
```

Comment: Can a number appear more than once? Is 1234 a different combination than 1243?

Comment: Yes, those would be two separate combinations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
for cc in permgen(items[:i]+items[i+1:],n-1):
```

You're basically saying "get a number, than add another one *different* from ir, repeat n times, then return a list of these digits. That's going to give you numbers where no digit appears more than once. If you change that line to:

```
for cc in permgen(items,n-1):
```

then you get all combinations.

Answer (score 12):

If you have python 2.6, why not use [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)?

```
from itertools import combinations
combinations(range(10), 4)
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [itertools' combinatoric generators](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html):

```
>>> from itertools import combinations, permutations, product
>>> def pp(chunks):
...     print(' '.join(map(''.join, chunks)))
...
>>> pp(combinations('012', 2))
01 02 12
>>> pp(permutations('012', 2))
01 02 10 12 20 21
>>> pp(product('012', repeat=2))
00 01 02 10 11 12 20 21 22
>>> from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
>>> pp(combinations_with_replacement('012', 2))
00 01 02 11 12 22
```

[`combinations_with_replacement`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) is available in Python 3.1 (or 2.7).

It seems that [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is the most suitable for your task.

Answer (score 0):

```
int ra;
for(ra=0,ra<10000;ra++) printf("%04u\n",ra);
```

Comment: The Python compiler will surely have a field day with THIS code...;-)